# Java how to return an enums value and name (Cards)

Tags: java, oop, enums, playing-cards

I'm to creating a blackjack game and i'm trying to figure out how to deal the card and have it display the value and the name. The reason I went with two properties was purely logic based when it comes to dealing with the Ace as being a 1 or 11. Haven't gotten to that point yet just figured i'd include that if anyone was wondering. here is what I have so far. I appreciate any help! I included the error i'm getting below as a comment

```
import java.util.Random;
public class CardDeck {
public enum Cards {
    ACE_SPADES (1, 11),
    ACE_HEARTS (1, 11),
    ACE_CLOVES (1, 11),
    ACE_DIAMONDS (1, 11),
    TWO_SPADES (2, 2),
    TWO_HEARTS (2, 2),
    TWO_CLOVES (2, 2),
    TWO_DIAMONDS (2, 2),
    THREE_SPADES (3, 3),
    THREE_HEARTS (3, 3),
    THREE_CLOVES (3, 3),
    THREE_DIAMONDS (3, 3),
    FOUR_SPADES (4, 4),
    FOUR_HEARTS (4, 4),
    FOUR_CLOVES (4, 4),
    FOUR_DIAMONDS (4, 4),
    FIVE_SPADES (5, 5),
    FIVE_HEARTS (5, 5),
    FIVE_CLOVES (5, 5),
    FIVE_DIAMONDS (5, 5),
    SIX_SPADES (6, 6),
    SIX_HEARTS (6, 6),
    SIX_CLOVES (6, 6),
    SIX_DIAMONDS (6, 6),
    SEVEN_SPADES (7, 7),
    SEVEN_HEARTS (7, 7),
    SEVEN_CLOVES (7, 7),
    SEVEN_DIAMONDS (7, 7),
    EIGHT_SPADES (8, 8),
    EIGHT_HEARTS (8, 8),
    EIGHT_CLOVES (8, 8),
    EIGHT_DIAMONDS (8, 8),
    NINE_SPADES (9, 9),
    NINE_HEARTS (9, 9),
    NINE_CLOVES (9, 9),
    NINE_DIAMONDS (9, 9),
    TEN_SPADES (10, 10),
    TEN_HEARTS (10, 10),
    TEN_CLOVES (10, 10),
    TEN_DIAMONDS (10, 10),
    JACK_SPADES (10, 10),
    JACK_HEARTS (10, 10),
    JACK_CLOVES (10, 10),
    JACK_DIAMONDS (10, 10),
    QUEEN_SPADES (10, 10),
    QUEEN_HEARTS (10, 10),
    QUEEN_CLOVES (10, 10),
    QUEEN_DIAMONDS (10, 10),
    KING_SPADES (10, 10),
    KING_HEARTS (10, 10),
    KING_CLOVES (10, 10),
    KING_DIAMONDS (10, 10);

    public final int faceValue1;
    public final int faceValue2;

    private Cards(int faceValue1, int faceValue2) {
        this.faceValue1 = faceValue1;
        this.faceValue2 = faceValue2;
    }

    public String toString() {    //  error: non-static method name() cannot 
                                         be referenced from a static context
        return Cards.name();
    }

    public int getFaceValue1() {
        return faceValue1;
    }

    public int getFaceValue2() {
        return faceValue2;
    }
}
Cards[] deck;

public CardDeck() {
    deck = new Cards[52];
    int i = 0;
    while(i<52) {
        for(Cards card : Cards.values()) {
            deck[i] = card;
            i++;
        }
    }
    shuffle(deck);                              
}
//This will return the first card after shuffling.
public Cards deal() {
    Cards[] cardReturn = new Cards[1];
    cardReturn[0] = deck[0];                 
    Cards[] tempArr = new Cards[deck.length - 1];    
    for(int i=1; i<deck.length; i++) {
        tempArr[i-1] = deck[i];         
    }
    deck = new Cards[tempArr.length];    
    deck = tempArr;                      
    return cardReturn[0];
} 

//this shuffles the deck
public void shuffle(Cards[] deckToShuffle) {
    int index;
    Cards[] temp = new Cards[1];
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = deckToShuffle.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
        temp[0] = deckToShuffle[index];     
        deckToShuffle[index] = deckToShuffle[i];
        deckToShuffle[i] = temp[0];     
      }
     deck = deckToShuffle;
}       
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept. One thing: avoid stating "can anyone help" as that sentence is normally an indication of a question that is too unclear / broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: don't call

```
 Cards.name()
```

But simply

```
 name()
```

To get your return value.

Beyond that: you are over-doing. You want two enums, one for card value, one for card suite. And then you have a card class that has two fields to hold value and suit.

Having all values times 4 as of now in one enum will make your code much more complicated than it ought to be.

There is also no point in making the value fields both public and having a getter method. Better make the fields private.

Finally, I don't like the naming of just calling them face value 1 and 2. But I don't have a better idea right now.

Comment: simple enough! Thank you! and yes i was thinking the same thing, i may just scrub everything and start over doing it that way.

Comment: Often that isn't bad idea. It helps to really throw away stuff and to try to come up with new ideas. Ideally you would do tdd... When writing test code first you often notice quickly when your design idea isn't "right".